# How to make interactive filter in power bi between 2 pages (not slicer)

Tags: filter, powerbi, dashboard, powerbi-desktop, slicers

I have a case where I have to make interactive filtering on few sheets.

Explanation:

suppose page 1 and 2 have part_nbr field in filter pane and both of the pages have matrix visual in it.
i want to make the interaction between this filter of both pages such that if I choose part_nbr as 1234 in page 1 then page 2 also show the visuals (matix) for part_nbr 1234 and I don't want to show slicer for part_nbr on either of the sheets.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add same slicer in all pages and Sync them so that the selected value apply same filter on each page. But, if you are not interested to show the slicer visual on each page, the work around is- hide Slicers from other pages after applying the Sync option. This way end user will only see Slicer on 1 page but it will work as per your expectation.

to hide the slicer, select the Slicer and then go to **Format** tab. Select the **Selection** option and set **show/hide** option as per your requirement.

[image]